# Ansicon on Windows 8 only runs once in a new "cmd /d"

Tags: windows-8, ansicon

I've installed Ansicon from the `ansi160.zip`, which I placed in a new `C:\Program Files (x86)\ansicon` directory and unzipped. From a command prompt in the x86 directory I uninstalled, reinstalled, and attempted to log on all different log levels. In each case it crashed with an **"ANSI Console has stopped working"** dialogue box. In each case I got a useless log:

```
ANSICON v1.60 log (7) started 2015-04-27 9:50:03
```

with nothing else.

However, when I opened a new `cmd /d` session, ***the first*** Ansicon session produced a lot more:

```
ANSICON v1.60 log (7) started 2015-04-27 9:56:09

ansicon (1744): WriteFile->
ansicon (1744): WriteConsoleA: 1 "\e"
ansicon (1744): WriteFile->
ansicon (1744): WriteConsoleA: 1 "["
ansicon (1744): WriteFile->
ansicon (1744): WriteConsoleA: 1 "m"
ansicon (1744): Unloading
ansicon (1744): Unhooking ansicon.exe
ansicon (1744):   CreateProcessW
ansicon (1744):   GetEnvironmentVariableW
ansicon (1744):   GetProcAddress
ansicon (1744):   LoadLibraryExW
ansicon (1744):   LoadLibraryW
ansicon (1744):   WriteFile
ansicon (1744): Unhooking ntdll.dll
ansicon (1744): Unhooking KERNELBASE.dll
ansicon (1744): Unhooking ADVAPI32.dll
ansicon (1744):   GetProcAddress
ansicon (1744):   LoadLibraryA
ansicon (1744):   LoadLibraryW
ansicon (1744):   WriteFile
ansicon (1744):   LoadLibraryExW
ansicon (1744): Unhooking msvcrt.dll
ansicon (1744):   WriteConsoleW
ansicon (1744):   WriteFile
ansicon (1744):   GetProcAddress
ansicon (1744):   LoadLibraryExW
ansicon (1744):   CreateProcessA
ansicon (1744):   CreateProcessW
ansicon (1744): Unhooking USER32.dll
ansicon (1744):   GetProcAddress
ansicon (1744):   LoadLibraryExW
ansicon (1744):   CreateProcessW
ansicon (1744): Unhooking sechost.dll
ansicon (1744):   LoadLibraryExW
ansicon (1744):   GetProcAddress
ansicon (1744): Unhooking RPCRT4.dll
ansicon (1744):   LoadLibraryExW
ansicon (1744):   GetProcAddress
ansicon (1744): Unhooking GDI32.dll
ansicon (1744):   WriteFile
ansicon (1744):   LoadLibraryExA
ansicon (1744):   LoadLibraryExW
ansicon (1744):   GetProcAddress
ansicon (1744): Unhooking IMM32.DLL
ansicon (1744):   LoadLibraryExW
ansicon (1744):   GetProcAddress
ansicon (1744): Unhooking MSCTF.dll
ansicon (1744):   LoadLibraryExW
ansicon (1744):   GetProcAddress
ansicon (1744):   CreateProcessW
ansicon (1744):   GetEnvironmentVariableW
ansicon (1744): Unhooking completed
ANSICON v1.60 log (29) started 2015-04-27 9:56:09
cmd (12928): WriteConsoleW: 2 "\r\n"
cmd (12928): WriteConsoleW: 35 "C:\Program Files (x86)\ansicon\x64>"
```

But then it crashed, and my next attempt with `-l29` in the same session wouldn't work. `ansicon -p` works, or at least doesn't crash, but I don't see its usefulness since the next invocation of ansicon in the same session (or by cucumber) crashes.

Here is [someone else's Ansicon help request](https://github.com/adoxa/ansicon/issues/21) that only helped me a little. I need Ansicon because cucumber is very difficult to use without it.

/ver: Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600]
Windows 8.1
Dell Inspiron 5447

*I just realized this is the wrong place since I'm using it as a 64-bit app.

Answer (score 0):

adoxa appears to have fixed this issue in [version 1.70](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=D18DE9C2F9D17ED!127&authkey=!ADZkdErqDeWb2cg&ithint=file%2Czip).